# How to Prevent Dropbox Access Elsewhere when Symlink?

Tags: symlink, dropbox, deleted-files

I have the symbolic link

```
ln -s $HOME/BTsync/masi/ $HOME/Dropbox/
```

I notice that contents in Dropbox GUI on Internet Browser are in conflict where `masi` directory has old files. I delete the directory in Dropbox's GUI.

- Result: `$HOME/BTsync/masi/` directory becomes empty.
- Expected result: `$HOME/BTsync/masi/` stays untouched and contents of `$HOME/Dropbox/masi` are updated.

I contacted BTsync support about the case too. I do not contact Dropbox because they have bad customer service and never answer their questions.

@Charles' answer confirms that Dropbox does not support Symlinks but take authority of your system in their hands. I do not like this.

---

How Can you Prevent Dropbox Access Elsewhere than Dropbox Folder in Your System?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox apparently [doesn't support symlinks](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/es/community/posts/202585995-Deleting-a-folder-in-Dropbox-cloud-which-was-a-symbolic-link-will-delete-the-original-files). So deleting a symlink from the Dropbox GUI deletes the link, as well as the items pointed to.

Comment: It is unbelievable. How can you Dropbox have authority of removing files elsewhere in my system? I do not like that the application has authority in messing up what they want.